# MFC - Sending MouseMove to an Unity application

Tags: c++, mfc, unity-game-engine, mousemove, postmessage

I want to send MouseMove commands to an application written in Unity using MFC (C++). Basically, I'm sending mouse clicks and it works very well. See the code:

```
HWND window = GetCurrentTargetHandle();
PostMessage(window, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, 0);
PostMessage(window, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, 0);
```

Now, I want to send mouse movements, to make the view change. For example, if I move my physical mouse, okay, it works. But, if I try to send MouseMove to the Unity window, it does nothing.

I have tryed:

```
INPUT input;
::ZeroMemory(&input, sizeof(INPUT));
input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
input.mi.dx = x;
input.mi.dy = current_y;
input.mi.dwFlags = (MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE);
::SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
```

Also:

```
POINT lp;
GetCursorPos(&lp);
::SendMessage(window, MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, MAKEWPARAM(x, lp.y), MAKELPARAM(x, lp.y));
```

Does anybody know what I should do?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried posting WM_MOUSEMOVE with the appropriate coordinates?

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: First, let's make sure I understand exactly what you are trying to accomplish.  Are you trying to move the mouse programmatically?

Comment: Yes, but not only for the user to see it on the screen, but also move the character in the game.

Comment: Updating the screen typically happens during the paint cycle (eg. OnDraw handler).  It's during that time that you will "move" characters.  And, how you do it will be dependent upon what technology (eg. OpenGL, DirectX) you use to render to the screen.